# Getting 404 on a defined ressource with in path parameter

Tags: flask-restful, connexion

I started to learn Python with connexion and flask and got stuck resolving an issue. Even after taking a long break I cannot see where I am wrong and need some advise.
I created a swagger API definition which maps /api/blacklist/{zipcode} to a function. However when I try to access /api/blacklist/12345 I receive a 404. The YAML is located here:

https://github.com/TheHasgarion/pythonflaskrest/blob/master/api.yml

The mapping for /api/blacklist/ works just fine. BTW, even accessing /api/blacklist/ gives me a 404.

The server log says:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2019 19:52:09] "GET /api/blacklist/12345 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2019 19:57:16] "GET /api/blacklist HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2019 19:57:18] "GET /api/blacklist/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Thank you very much in advance for guidance.

Comment: OK now I changed the yaml to :
`paths:
  /blacklist/{zipcode}:
    get:
      parameters:
          - in: path
            name: zipcode
            description: "the zipcode to look up"
            type: **integer**`
changing type from _number_ to _integer_works. But I don't understand why

Comment: The page https://github.com/TheHasgarion/pythonflaskrest/blob/master/api.yml is returning Not Found. Btw the change from "number" to "integer" works because the  type casting https://github.com/zalando/connexion#type-casting . Number is converted to float and Integer to  int , in your case you are passing 12345 and this is a int not a float. Hope its helps.

Comment: @KevinMartins thank you, that helped :) Sorry for the broken permissions on gtithub, I fixed it :)

Comment: No problem :) can you mark this question has solved?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you need to use integer as type, not number. Whyever 'number' means 'float' :-)